# Jquery, get value of multidimentional array key

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array, onchange

I've got an html form (I cannot edit) with no ID and a name attribute like this:

name="metadata[team-member][42][name]"

I need to do two things.

1. Detect if and instance of metadata[team-member] is ever changed or updated.
2. get the INT held in teh second array level if so.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
$('[name="metadata[team-member]"]').on('change', function() {
    alert('woo');
});
```

And that doesn't even detect the field being changed.
For reference, this is a list of members name, email and status. so that other fields wil be:
name="metadata[team-member][42][email] etc... But I don't care about that, I just need the INT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because your selector is wrong, the name attribute is `metadata[team-member][42][name]` in this case. Since you are using [attribute equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) filter it looks for complete match

You might change the selector to use [starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector, which will filtler all elements whose name starts with `metadata[team-member]`

```
$('[name^="metadata[team-member]"]')
```

To get the int value inside the handler

```
var name = this.name;
var intpart = 'metadata[team-member][42][name]'.match(/\[(\d+)\]/)[1];
```

Comment: This is the solution I used.. I'll update my question to include my specific version soon.. many thanks..!

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to get the id from name:

```
$('[name^="metadata[team-member]"]').on('change', function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    var id = parseInt(name.match(/\d{2}/)[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I sketched a small sample

```
$('input[name="test[test]"]').on('change', function(){

  alert(123);

});
```

look at this
http://jsbin.com/oyogec/1/